# Why in this code snippet is the outer scope of the arrow function in `showList` instead of `forEach`?

Tags: javascript, this

So here is the code snippet from this [modern JavaScript tutorial](https://javascript.info/arrow-functions):

```js
let group = {
  title: "Our Group",
  students: ["John", "Pete", "Alice"],

  showList() {
    this.students.forEach(
      student => alert(this.title + ': ' + student)
    );
  }
};

group.showList();
```

The tutorial tries to explain `this` in an arrow function, and it says:

> Here in forEach, the arrow function is used, so `this.title` in it is exactly the same as in the outer method showList. That is: group.title.

We know `this` in an arrow function is determined lexically. So the scope chain should be:

```
global--> showList-->forEach-->arrow function
```

In this case, the outer scope of arrow function should be `forEach` instead of `showList`. Thus `this` in an arrow function is exactly the same as in `forEach`, which should be `undefined` since there is no `thisArg` passed to `forEach`. But in fact, `this` is `group`, which means it is exactly the same as in `showList`.
So, it seems `forEach` doesn't hold a scope in this case? I am confused.

Comment: because you assign or create those methods in the scope of showList and lambdas share scope in js, also those cb get invoked not called ^^ no scope binding - furthermore arrow functions ignore bindings

Comment: The `forEach()` and the arrow function are one and the same scope. The scope of the `forEach()` is informed by the type of function (arrow vs. conventional) you pass to it.

Comment: Why arrow function is not in `forEach` scope?It should be from the perspective of lexical,right?I mean it just the same as `function( ){ ( )=>{ } }`(here the function is `forEach`)

Comment: @Estradiaz  arrow functions ignore bindings ,but its this will be the same as in its outer scope,which in this question is forEach

Comment: Hmm isnt it that those arrow functions are created in showList and then passed to forEach where it gets called like cb.call(undefined, ...args), but as those are arrow functions they keep there scope bindings to parent ctx, those are passed as callbacks not created in the scope of foreach

Comment: @Estradiaz Oh,you are right.forEach is just a call ,not a function body which will hold a lexical scope.I just misunderstand it since it looks like arrow function is wrapped in forEach.

Comment: Isn't your question obvious from just looking at the code, the scopes are as defined, inner being forEach and outer being the next level up the function itself.

Comment: @Chor does that mean you have found the answer of your question?

Comment: @YongQuan Yes.I figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the scope chain should be:
>
> ```
> global--> showList-->forEach-->arrow function
> ```

I think you are confused what "scope" means. It's a variable scope, in code typically delimited with braces `{…}`, the region in which any identifier always refers to the same variable.

There is no "`forEach` scope". It's just a function call. Just like there is no scope for the parameter list of the `alert(…)` call. There are only three scopes in your example:

```
global --> showList --> anonymous arrow function
```

There is also the [*call stack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack), outlining which function calls led to the execution of the current code. This does indeed contain `forEach`, which is calling the arrow function, which in turn will call the `alert` function. But this does not correspond to the scope in JavaScript (for which you will see more examples when learning about closures), which is why JavaScript is said to have [*lexical scope* and not *dynamic scope*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping_vs._dynamic_scoping) (where identifiers are resolved dynamically depending on where a function was called).

Comment: Yes.Now I know it.Embarrassing as I have confounded call stack and the scope.To figure out the scope chain,I should focus on where is the function defined,instead of where it is called

Answer (score 3):

> The error occurs because forEach runs functions with this=undefined by
>   default, so the attempt to access undefined.title is made.
>
> That doesn’t affect arrow functions, because they just don’t have
>   this.

source https://javascript.info/arrow-functions

> As we remember from the chapter Object methods, "this", arrow
>   functions do not have this. If this is accessed, it is taken from the
>   outside.

The outside function in this case is `showList` as you would realise that forEach is not a wrapping function for arrow function here instead it is just a call to a function which takes a callback.

Instead `showList` is the wrapping function. Hence it inherits this from `showList`

Perhaps this example will help you understand better:

```js
'use strict';

function hello(greet) {
  greet()
}

let group = {
  title: "Our Group",
  students: ["John", "Pete", "Alice"],


  showList() {
    hello(() => console.log("Hello " + this.title))
  }
};

group.showList();
```

Comment: This is fact.But what is the reason?Why `forEach()` doesn't wrap arrow function?

Answer (score 1):

Lexical scope is determined by where a function is **defined**.

You are **passing** the arrow function to `forEach`, so its scope has nothing to do with `forEach`.

It is the same reason that in this example, the function logs "one" and not "two":

```js
function one() {
    const value = "one";
    two( function() { console.log(value); } );
}

function two(argument) {
    const value = "two";
    argument();
}

one();
```

Answer (score 1):

Scope is only created when an object/function is created (in this case).

In the case of `.forEach`, you are merely calling a function that is already created by the engine, meaning you are not creating any scopes when calling `.forEach`.

Conversely, when you define:

```js
let group = {
  title: "Our Group",
  students: ["John", "Pete", "Alice"],

  showList() {
    this.students.forEach(
      student => alert(this.title + ': ' + student)
    );
  }
};
```

It translates to:

```js
let group = {
  title: "Our Group",
  students: ["John", "Pete", "Alice"],

  showList: function() {
    this.students.forEach(
      student => alert(this.title + ': ' + student)
    );
  }
};
```

You are creating a function named "showList", and therefore you are creating a scope.

Before the `showList()` function is created, you created the `group` object, thus creating another scope, which, in this case, is the parent scope of `showList()`.

Therefore, inside the `showList()` function, its `this` value is the `group` object.